# Adjust the length of animation clip to match cooldown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm planning on have several buttons to spawn monsters, all with a different cooldown. Is there a way to match the animation clip to be the same length as the cooldown of the button?

Here is an example: https://gyazo.com/0a2ae868e5458c701e1a258aac6dc59a

The animation is 1 second but the cooldown is 3 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
private void ButtonCooldown()
{
    if (GetComponent<Button>().interactable == false)
    {
        buttonTimer += Time.deltaTime;


        if (buttonTimer >= cooldown)
        {
            GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
            buttonTimer = 0;
        }
    }
}

public void DisableButton()
{
    GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
    myAnimatior.SetTrigger("ButtonCooldownAnimation");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adjust the according `Animator`'s [`speed`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-speed.html) to adjust it's overall playback speed.

E.g. something like

```
// Adjust in the inspector
[SerializeField] private float cooldownTime = 3;

// Already reference this via the Inspector if possible
[SerializeField] private Button button;

private void Awake ()
{
    // Do this only once!
    if(!button) button = GetComponemt<Button>();
}

public void DisableButton()
{
    button.interactable = false;

    // typo in Animator btw ;)
    myAnimatior.SetTrigger("ButtonCooldownAnimation");

    // Make the Animator play slower so the animation now takes 3 seconds
    myAnimatior.speed = 1/cooldownTime;

    // Instead of Update simply use Invoke here
    // Execute the method called WhenCooldownDone after cooldownTime seconds
    Invoke(nameof(WhenCooldownDone), cooldownTime);
}

private void WhenCooldownDone ()
{
    button.interactable = true;
    myAnimator.speed = 1;
}
```

As in the comments I would use [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) instead of constantly checking the states in `Update`. In particular never use `GetComponent`repeatedly in `Update`. It is very expensive. Always try to rather store the reference and reuse it.

Comment: Is it possible to directly affect the [AnimationState.length](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationState-length.html)?

Comment: @ErikOverflow I don't think so .. it is read only, isn't it? Also if you want to use the same AnimatorController with the same clips for multiple objects this would alter it for every Animator using it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i've tried adding your code, my button disables but the animation doesn't play at all.

Comment: I've updated my code similar to yours using the Invoke, that's all working now but i can't seem to get the time right 1/cooldown doesn't seem to match the length of the clip. What did you mean about use framerater increate of 1 multiplier?

Comment: I just saw in the docs it is clear: `1 is normal playback speed.` so `2` should be the double speed meaning half the time until the animation finishes. Since you said the animation is usually 1 second and you want to spread it to 3 seconds it should mean the `Animator.speed` has to be `1/3` to achieve that.